# $y = \arcsin(x)$: Find value of its second derivative evaluated at $\sqrt{3}/2$

Tags: calculus

Do you find the derivative and then plug in $\sqrt{3}/2$ into first derivative equation?

Comment: The second derivative of a function is the derivative of the derivative of that function.  It is a function in it's own right, so you can evaluate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should evaluate the second derivative and then plug in $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

$$y=arcsin(x)\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\implies \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-1(-2x)}{2}(1-x^2)^{-3/2}=x(1-x^2)^{-3/2}$$

Evaluating at $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, we have:

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(1-(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2)^{-3/2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(1-\frac{3}{4})^{-3/2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(\frac{1}{4})^{-3/2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(4)^{3/2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}8=4\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: I apologize if this confused you before I edited it, I misread $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ as $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: It's fine. Thank you so much for the solution!